# Clone Organization Between Azure DevOps Tenant

Tags: azure-devops

I have two completely separate tenants for my Azure DevOps(ex. **OldTenant** and **NewTenant**).

- **NewTenant** is clean and has no organization in it.
- **OldTenant** has Organization -> Project -> {Data}(ex. work-items, repo, pipelines etc.)
  So now I need to clone Tenant1 Organization and all specific data inside it to Tenant2.

I've googled a lot but there is no specific tool/utility or Microsoft guidance for the same scenario.